# Help needed from mod

Tags: support

**This may not be the right place to contact a mod, but I can explain why I am doing so.**

So yesterday(3 mar IST) my PSU blew up with cracking sound and smoke.luckily no other hardware was damaged.

I have no plans of restoring the PSU and have decided to sell the stuff at whatever price I may get.

While it will be recommended that I format the HDD before selling.But there was not much private stuff therein.I also don't want to spend more money on it.

The only stuff I would care for on the HDD are some passwords.I have changed all the passwords so they won't harm me.

The only thing left is the SE network login.I was logged in through that PC and didn't log out.

So to the main point, can a mod do something to help me out? Like logging me out or blocking the IP?

Or am I fearing for nothing?

For now I am logged in from android app for SE.

Comment: Moderators can clear your sessions, which will log you out of SE. If the password was saved on your HDD, there is nothing they could do about this.

Comment: @madscientist  There is no password for SE

Comment: @madscientist  Clearing the sessions seems to be a good choice

Comment: If you remember, did you login using your stackexchange account or google account?

Comment: @jobin I used a yahoo account.nyway the problem should be solved now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just cleared and invalidated all of your sessions.

Answer (score 3):

You may have this sorted, but you should be able to change the password easily.

If you go to [your profile](https://askubuntu.com/users/184942/aditya-patil) or [your StackExchange network profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/3186826/aditya-patil), and click 'my logins':
                                    [image]

Then you should be able to change the password:
[image: Click change password, or remove the account as you like]
Note also that the email *(removed in the above pic)* you may have used as the your username may also show, so you might want to sort something out about that.

Blocking the IP might not be much use unless it is a fixed global IP address for that machine - using the MAC address is a vague possibility, but even then the hard drive could be switched or the MAC address changed or something.

Hope this helps.